# Should I be concerned about this pivot point?

Tags: uv

I'm done modeling this figure, and I'm fixing to UV unwrap it. But before I do that, I want to make sure that everything is neat and ready. So I tried to apply the scale, rotation, and location of the objects. This is my first character I've ever done in Blender, so I'm not sure if this pivot point is behaving as it should or not. Here's what I mean.
[image]

So This beret type hat is parented to the main model. And it's location and scale and whatnot are applied. But the pivot point matches the model's pivot point. I tried to make the pivot point of the hat in the middle. Like this.
[image]
I set the origin to geometry, but that messed up the location. But if I apply the location, then the pivot point snaps back to the bottom of the model as it was before... Is that normal? When people model characters and parent objects to the mesh, is it okay for pivot point to be the same for every object that it is parented to, to be the same?
Well, thanks in advance everyone! I want to make sure that the UV unwrapping goes well, because it's the only thing in Blender I don't like doing. Is there anything else about applying location I need to know about before unwrapping?
Thanks again, and Godbless you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is good news: This doesn't matter, because all of this kind of stuff won't really affect UV unwrapping or texturing, and you can go back and change it later if you need to. You might start to run into problems if you have a non-uniform scale, so it's best to apply a scale before UV-unwrapping. Blender will give you a warning if this is the case.

When you apply location, that means you are setting the origin of that object to the origin of the x-y-z volume, so that is exactly expected behavior.

Where you want that pivot point mostly depends on how you intend to animate your mesh. If you're using an armature, and mapping parts of your mesh to bones, then it doesn't really matter where the object origins are. If you want to be able to animate that hat as its own object, it probably makes more sense to keep the origin in the center of the geometry, because that's the point about which you'll animate rotations.

You can change your origin in the Object menu under Set Origin. Typically you'll either Set Origin to Geometry, or Set Origin to 3D cursor if you need the origin to be somewhere specific, like at the hinge of a door as opposed to its center.

So for example, if you wanted to keep the hat where it is, with the hat's origin at its center of geometry, here is how you would go about it.

1. Select the hat. Object > Set Origin > To Geometry
2. SHIFT+click the character to select it as well and hit CTRL+P > Set Parent.
   [image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for your answer. It's good to hear a second opinion on the matter. But is there a way to parent the object, and retain it's own pivot point at the center of the hat? I mean, it's okay where it is, but I feel like it would be better at the center. But it moves when I apply it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you exactly. If you select first the hat, then your character and hit CTRL+P > Set Parent, that should parent the hat to your character without changing the hat's position or origin.

Comment: I parented the hat, but that causes the origin point to change to the world origin. I think it's some kind of glitch? I tried changing the median point to individual origin and all that. But it's not letting me keep the pivot point where I want it after the location is applied. I can upload some more pictures if that helps. Thank you again!

Comment: Hrm. Perhaps try Set Parent (Keep Transform) then? If that fails, you could also upload your file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and I could take a look.

Comment: Okay lemme try Keep transform. Be back in a sec.

Comment: Okay. that didn't work. I've never actually uploaded a .blend. I'll give that a shot. BRB.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=XVkP8ljV" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/XVkP8ljV/)

Comment: That works perfectly, and I really cannot thank you enough for sticking with me for this long. But the origin snaps back when apply location.

Comment: YW! And yes, when you apply location it snaps the origin back. That is the function of that command. In this case you wouldn't want to apply location.

Comment: Ooooooooh... That makes so much more sense now. I had no idea that there were case scenarios where the location should not be applied. Hopefully that does not mess with the unwrapping. But thank you SO VERY MUCH FOR TAKING THE TIME TO HELP ME! You've made the process a lot less painful for me.